# Ideas to properly rate-limit port 25

Tags: port

I need some ideas on properly rate-limiting port 25 on Xen VPS nodes. Ideal solution would be to have a set limit of outgoing emails for each VPS, with option to allow higher limits on a per-VPS basis.

Is there any easy way of doing this or I have to do iptables rules for all of the VPS-es?

Comment: Forgot to specify - limit should be on hourly basis.

Comment: Are these VPS nodes given to customers to do as they like with, or are they under your control as mail relays?  you could do something at iptables or mta level.

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://serverfault.com/posts/839989/edit) rather than clarify it using comments, thanks

Comment: @Matt They are given to customers.